# Making Installation Program using Rider IDE

Tags: c#, rider

As a user who migrated from VS to Rider, I was wondering what sort of options there are to create an installation program (Terms of Service etc) are available to the rider IDE. Is my best bet to use VS or is there a new feature of Rider that can develop these types of programs?

Comment: Except Visual Studio Setup Projects or ClickOnce which requires tight VS integration, other major options (WiX, Inno Setup, InstallAware and more) to create installers don't require IDE integration, so can be used no mater what IDE you choose.

Comment: Check-out _[ClickOnceMore](http://www.clickoncemore.net/)_.  It's a stand-alone GUI tool and because it's been designed for CI systems in mind `does not require VS at all`.  After defining your setup you can invoke it via the **command-line** that you could easily invoke from Rider

Answer (score 0):

Rider has a proper support for WiX setup projects.
But you can not create such project from Rider New Project wizard, see the next issue in JetBrains issue tracker:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-61281

You can use this guide to create a project and then open and develop it in Rider:
https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/getting-started/putting-it-to-use/